# How to create calculating driver?

Tags: c++, c, wdk

How to create a driver which calculate something in the body. I tried to create a loop, but I have an error in compilation
[https://i.stack.imgur.com/4nall.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hHRLF.jpg)

```
// TestDriver.c

#include <ntddk.h>

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath);
VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject);

#pragma alloc_text(INIT, DriverEntry)
#pragma alloc_text(PAGE, UnloadRoutine)

NTSTATUS DriverEntry(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject, IN PUNICODE_STRING RegistryPath)
{
  DriverObject->DriverUnload = UnloadRoutine;
  while('true'){
  int role = pow(2,20);
}
  DbgPrint("Hello, Alexey Baranovkiy!\n");
  return STATUS_SUCCESS;
}

VOID UnloadRoutine(IN PDRIVER_OBJECT DriverObject)
{
  DbgPrint("Bye!\n");
}
```

Comment: May be you need something like `-lm` ?

Comment: You're assigning the results of `pow` to an `int` but it is a floating point function. Is that what you intended? Using floating point in drivers isn't commonly done and special steps are required.

Answer (score 6):

Essentially, in a 32-bit windows driver, you can't use floating point "as you like". I would say most of the time, you are probably doing something wrong if you need to perform floating point calculations in a driver.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff565388%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

The standard floating point calculations are not suited to be used in drivers, so you will most likely also need to write your own functions.

Of course, the function you are using will be perfectly replacable with a simple

```
role = 1 << 20;
```

However, doing `pow(1.5, 3.7)` will not be quite so easy to calculate without floating point, and if your goal is to calculate pretty much any floating point calculation, then you will have an interesting challenge ahead of you. There is no real ready made solution.

Comment: Thank`s mate. Your advice help me to compile the code :) But now KMDManage don`t want to Register my sys file...I think cause I had the infinite loop. Someone now can I create main inside??? I had different errors when I tried to make it

Comment: Well, you don't really want an infinite loop in a driver, do you? And yes, the driver is registered after your DriverEntry has returned, so putting an infinite loop there is a really poor choice. I

Comment: I suspect you want to solve whatever you are trying to do in some other way.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, well first I think your confused some what; to write a driver you need a data sheet for a device - that has the transaction information on it.

You then write a function based on the opening of a transaction, then what you actually want to do, and then close the transaction.

Thus, you need to write a driver for a device your using on someones body. So for example flashing a light on the arm, and then getting light data back from a camera; using the degree of a colour to give a blood pressure reading - its that simple...